# thread synchronization for two threads using one semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

I want to synchronize threads to print from 1 to 20 with odd numbers printed by thread1 and even numbers printed by thread2

I achieved this with two semaphores.

Questions:

1) Can this be achieved using only one semaphore ?

2) Is there any efficient way to achieve this ?

If possible please provide example too.

```
sem_t bin_sem1, bin_sem2;
int count = 1;

int main()
{
    int ret;
    pthread_t a_thread, b_thread;

    ret = sem_init(&bin_sem1, 0, 1);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("semaphore1 initialization failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ret = sem_init(&bin_sem2, 0, 0);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("semaphore2 initialization failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, thread_fun1, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("Thread1 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&b_thread, NULL, thread_fun2, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("Thread2 creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Waiting for threads to finish\n");
    ret = pthread_join(a_thread, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("Thread1 join failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Thread1 joined");

    ret = pthread_join(b_thread, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("Thread2 join failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Thread2 joined");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *thread_fun1(void *arg)
{
    int val=0, val2=0;
    while (count < 20)
    {
        sem_wait(&bin_sem1);
        sem_getvalue(&bin_sem1, &val);sem_getvalue(&bin_sem2, &val2);
        printf("T 1 : after wait  : sem 1 = %d, sem 2 = %d\n", val, val2);

        printf("T 1 : count = %d\n", count++);

        sem_post(&bin_sem2);
        sem_getvalue(&bin_sem1, &val);sem_getvalue(&bin_sem2, &val2);
        printf("T 1 : after post  : sem 1 = %d, sem 2 = %d\n", val, val2);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *thread_fun2(void *arg)
{
    int val=0, val2=0;
    while (count < 20)
    {
        sem_wait(&bin_sem2);
        sem_getvalue(&bin_sem1, &val);sem_getvalue(&bin_sem2, &val2);
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tT 2 : after wait  : sem 1 = %d, sem 2 = %d\n", val, val2);

        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tT 2 : count = %d\n", count++);

        sem_post(&bin_sem1);
        sem_getvalue(&bin_sem1, &val);sem_getvalue(&bin_sem2, &val2);
        printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tT 2 : after post  : sem 1 = %d, sem 2 = %d\n", val, val2);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using semaphores, why not use atomic types?

Comment: @Linus in general, because you cannot wait on them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is is possible to use only one semaphore but in a sort of hacky way. Instead of using a semaphore like a mutex, you could use it store the actual value and then print even numbers in thread 2 and odd numbers in thread 1. Here is an example but instead of printing from 1 to 20, it prints from 20 to 1 but that can easily be modified if required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void *a_func(void *arg) {
  sem_t *mySem = (sem_t *) arg;
  int value = 20;

  while (value > 0) {
    if (value % 2 == 1) {
      printf("thread 1 : %d\n", value);
      sem_wait(mySem);
    }
    sem_getvalue(mySem, &value);
  }
}

void *b_func(void *arg) {
  sem_t *mySem = (sem_t *) arg;
  int value = 20;

  while (value > 0) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
      printf("thread 2 : %d\n", value);
      sem_wait(mySem);
    }
    sem_getvalue(mySem, &value);
  }
}

int main() {
  sem_t mySem;
  pthread_t a_thread, b_thread;

  if (sem_init(&mySem, 0, 20)) {
    // handle error
  }

  if (pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, a_func, &mySem)) {
    // handle error
  }

  if (pthread_create(&b_thread, NULL, b_func, &mySem)) {
    // handle error
  }

  // wait for threads to finish
  pthread_join(a_thread, NULL);
  pthread_join(b_thread, NULL);
}
```

However, semaphores are rarely used in this manner and therefore I suggest using atomic types instead which are much more modern and is perfect for your usecase. Here is a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

void *a_func(void *arg) {
  atomic_int *myInt = (atomic_int *) arg;
  int value = 20;

  while (value > 0) {
    if (value % 2 == 1) {
      //printf("thread 1 : %d\n", value);
      value = atomic_fetch_sub(myInt, 1) + 1;
      continue;
    }
    value = atomic_load(myInt);
  }
}

void *b_func(void *arg) {
  atomic_int *myInt = (atomic_int *) arg;
  int value = 20;

  while (value > 0) {
    if (value % 2 == 0) {
      //printf("thread 2 : %d\n", value);
      value = atomic_fetch_sub(myInt, 1) + 1;
      continue;
    }
    value = atomic_load(myInt);
  }
}

int main() {
  atomic_int myInt = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(20); // set myInt to 20
  pthread_t a_thread, b_thread;

  if (pthread_create(&a_thread, NULL, a_func, &myInt)) {
    // handle error
  }

  if (pthread_create(&b_thread, NULL, b_func, &myInt)) {
    // handle error
  }

  // wait for threads to finish
  pthread_join(a_thread, NULL);
  pthread_join(b_thread, NULL);
}
```

As for performance both the single semaphore program and the atomic type based program runs much faster than the code you provided. However, on this scale where you only use numbers in the range of 1-20 the perforamnce differences is negligible.